# HostListener not being listened on CdkDragDrop event using custom directive Angular6

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular6, angular-material-6, angular-cdk

- I am working with angular6 CdkDragDrop module.
- I tried to create a custom directive **"appRenderControl"** that
  would listen to **CdkDragDrop** event, when an item is dropped into
  the container.

  However, the directive is not being listened at the
  moment.

Below is my code, can anyone please point out what is going wrong.

```
<div id='main'>
  <div [style.background]="'blue'" id='components'>
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-title>Components</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content >

        <div id="controls" cdkDropList  #inactiveList="cdkDropList" 
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[activeList]">

            <div class="control-button" *ngFor="let item of  controls" cdkDrag >
              <div class="custom-drag-drop" *cdkDragPlaceholder>{{item}} </div>
              {{item}}
            </div>

        </div>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>

   <div [style.background]="'white'" id='preview' cdkDropList
   #activeList='cdkDropList' appRenderControl>
    </div>
</div>


  </div>

</div>
```

Directive.ts

```
import { Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragDrop} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appRenderControl]'
})
export class RenderControlDirective {

constructor() {

}

  //This is not being listened 
@HostListener('CdkDragDrop', ['$event'])
onItemDropped(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>): void {
   console.log('directive being called')
 }
}
```

Comment: Refer :  https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-drag-and-drop-with-the-angular-material-cdk-2e0237857290, this might be helpful